# How do i make my model glow?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement

I'm quite new to Blender and have been trying for days to give my character a glow effect on his eyes and arm, and i have been using three textures for this, but it seems I can only keep two of these textures activated at a time.
So at the moment it seems like i have to choose between bump and textured,

[image]

or flat textured and glowing.

[image]

Here are the textures I'm trying to use:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm sure there is a obvious way to solve this but i can't see it and no tutorial i have watched has brought me any closer to an answer.

How do I solve this?

My node setup is a mess as I began this week to learn about it.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Could you provide some picture of you node setting? Or upload the blend file using this link https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ? That may help to understand your issue

Comment: I will update my post to show my node setup.

Comment: Hard to say, what you want to do with this setting. Only the selected output will be rendered. For the other aspect, the emissive texture should be to emission.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am extremely new to this. But when i connect emission to emission, the whole model turns pink. But if I remove the emission and connect the texture image to the principal BSDF emmision, i get the textures to overlap perfectly, but with no glow effect or a way to control glow strength.

Comment: FrostBird, I've tried the textures linked in your question on a flat plane model. This could be insignificant (image format, etc.). The best is to upload your model including (packing) the textures with it as a blend file. Maybe someone here could help on this basis.

Comment: I managed to find the solution through trial and error. Should I upload my node setup somewhere for future refrence?

Comment: The better to have an answer is the blend file uploaded using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, but we can understand that you don't want to upload the model. So it's up to you.